# mySQL select with old table and new table query

Tags: mysql

Hey all i am trying to figure out why my query code below does not seem to work:

```
SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
FROM productr, productr2010
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2010/12/01' AND itemRUDate <= '2011/01/22'
GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY SumOf DESC
```

The table productr2010 is the **OLD** data and productr is a brand new table for this year (2011). When i try running the query i get this:

```
Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

I'm not sure what i need to do in order for it to grad data from both tables? I've also tried this:

```
SELECT productr.id, productr.itemName, productr.itemRUDate, Sum(productr.itemsSold) AS    SumOf
FROM productr, productr2010
WHERE productr.itemRUDate >= '2010/12/01' AND productr.itemRUDate <= '2011/01/22'
AND productr2010.itemRUDate >= '2010/12/01' AND productr2010.itemRUDate <= '2011/01/22'
GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY SumOf DESC
```

And i get only the data from the productr table and not that and productr2010 table.

I'm sure i am just overlooking something easy..

**UPDATE**

Got it using this:

```
SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS    SumOf
FROM productr
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2010/12/01' AND itemRUDate <= '2011/01/22'
GROUP BY itemName
UNION
SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS    SumOf
FROM productr2010
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2010/12/01' AND itemRUDate <= '2011/01/22'
GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY SumOf DESC
```

David

Comment: You can simplify the date comparisons in your WHERE clause: `WHERE itemRUDate BETWEEN '2010/12/01' AND '2011/01/22'`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are not specifying any JOIN conditions to link the records in the two tables.  You will, therefore, get a cartesian JOIN (a very large result set composed of every row in productr JOINed to every row in productr2010, almost certainly not what you want).

Secondly, you normally want to include all non-aggregated columns (in this case id, itemname and itemRUdate) in the GROUP BY clause.  MySQL, alone among major databases TTBOMK, allows you not to do this but you will get unspecified values from the non-GROUP BY columns if those columns do not contain all the same data.

Finally, because you are joining to tables with the same column names, you *must* prefix *each* reference to a column with the name of the table you want to get it from, otherwise the engine will decide for you where the data comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select your data from both joined tables, as below.

```
SELECT productr.itemName, productr2010.itemName,
```

This will result in two separate columns for each piece of data, rather than a single column with both tables' data.